# What is the fastest way to group values based on multiple key columns in RDD using Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

My data is a file containing over 2 million rows of employee records. Each row has 15 fields of employee features, including name, DOB, ssn, etc. Example:

```
ID|name|DOB|address|SSN|...
1|James Bond|10/01/1990|1000 Stanford Ave|123456789|...
2|Jason Bourne|05/17/1987|2000 Yale Rd|987654321|...
3|James Bond|10/01/1990|5000 Berkeley Dr|123456789|...
```

I need to group the data by a number of columns and aggregate the employee's ID (first column) with the same key. The number and name of the key columns are passed into the function as parameters.

For example, if the key columns include "name, DOB, SSN", the data will be grouped as

```
(James Bond, 10/01/1990, 123456789), List(1,3)
(Jason Bourne, 05/17/1987, 987654321), List(2)
```

And the final output is

```
List(1,3)
List(2)
```

I am new to Scala and Spark. What I did to solve this problem is: read the data as RDD, and tried using groupBy, reduceByKey, and foldByKey to implement the function based on my research on StackOverflow. Among them, I found groupBy was the slowest, and foldByKey was the fastest. My implementation with **foldByKey** is:

```
val buckets = data.map(row => (idx.map(i => row(i)) -> (row(0) :: Nil)))
                  .foldByKey(List[String]())((acc, e) => acc ::: e).values
```

**My question is: Is there faster implementation than mine using foldByKey on RDD?**

Update: I've read posts on StackOverflow and understand groupByKey may be very slow on large dataset. This is why I did avoid groupByKey and ended up with foldByKey. However, this is not the question I asked. I am looking for an even faster implementation, or the optimal implementation in terms of processing time with the fixed hardware setting. (The processing of 2 million records now requires ~15 minutes.) I was told that converting RDD to DataFrame and call groupBy can be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some details on each of these first to understand how they work.

**groupByKey** runs slow as all the key-value pairs are shuffled around. This is a lot of unnessary data to being transferred over the network.

**reduceByKey** works much better on a large dataset. That's because Spark knows it can combine output with a common key on each partition before shuffling the data.

**combineByKey** can be used when you are combining elements but your return type differs from your input value type.

**foldByKey** merges the values for each key using an associative function and a neutral "zero value".

So avoid **groupbyKey**. Hoping this helps.

Cheers !